# How I extend hdfs disk?

Tags: hdfs, disk

**I'm using Ambari , HDFS disk usage is full , How should I do to extend storage**  ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your DataNodes are full, you add more DataNodes.

If your DataNodes have spare disk space, you can add directories in the
`dfs.datanode.data.dir` property.